# How to get pop-up with ngDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I couldn't get this **ngDialog** module working with **AngularJs** so looking for some hint where I went wrong.

My Json file named *abc.json*

```
[{"id":
  [
      {
          "value":"text_id",
          "desc":"Text id"
      },
      {
          "value":"group_id",
          "desc":"Group id"
      },
  ]
}]
```

Angular Controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mine.controllers', [])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http',  function($scope, $sce, $http, ngDialog) {
            $http.get('abc.json')
            .success(function(data) {
              $scope.ids = data;
            });
            $scope.openPlain = function (message) {
              ngDialog.open(message);
            };
          }]);
```

And finally the HTML

```
<body ng-app="mine">
    <table ng-controller="myController">
        <tr ng-repeat="datas in ids">
            <td>
                <span ng-repeat="iden in datas.id">
                    <a href="" ng-click='openPlain("{{ iden.desc }}")'>{{ iden.value }}</a>, 
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.2.3/js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ys01yoLk/), but I couldn't make it work with JsFiddle either, some different error.

In my local machine I don't get any error when the DOM loads and the `value` are displayed correctly from the JSON file. However when I click the link, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
```

So I am guessing the **ngDialog** is not loaded or something else.

Comment: I think your `$scope ` has the wrong scope in application. I change your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ys01yoLk/1/) . Before you hit your link, click on run fiddle. May be this will work for you.

Comment: but in your fiddle angular `$scope` is out of controller

Comment: yeah. May I did not get your problem at all, but you need to define your $scope.openPlain out of the controller. This will fix your `TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined`

Comment: you cannot use Angular `$scope` outside of angular controller. See the example in ngDialog here... https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog it uses angular scope to run its methods

Answer (score 2):

You didn't inject ngDialog into your controller properly:

This line:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http',  
                              function($scope, $sce, $http, ngDialog) {
```

This should be:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', 'ngDialog', 
                             function($scope, $sce, $http, ngDialog) {
```

Here is your fiddle working.  You didn't specify the template to use to layout the dialog.  Anyway this will get you a bit further along.

http://jsfiddle.net/ys01yoLk/5/

Comment: thanks... the Injection in model eliminates the error.. however the pop-up is not displaying though

Comment: Well this is where you need to go back to ngDialog and figure out how it works.  I read the docs, but I didn't see it actually working to show the popup.  After looking at the example looks like there is a lot more to setup.  You probably should read these before continuing: https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog/blob/master/example/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You had a problem of injection and you have to call the CSS files in your HTML.
Controller

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', 'ngDialog', 
                             function($scope, $sce, $http, ngDialog) {
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-dialog/0.2.3/css/ngDialog.css" />
```

Then it works !